# Accessing the initializer of a static constexpr in LLVM C++17

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

In an LLVM-9.x plugin, I'd like to access the initializer (`= 42`) associated with variable `Y` in the template specialization `T<42> foo`:

```
template<int X>
class T {
  //Clang produces different ASTs on this code in C++14 and C++17
  //(in 17, there's no initializer for Y (= 42) in the specialized
  //class foo below).
  static constexpr int Y = X;
};
T<42> foo;
```

With `clang++ -std=c++14` I get an AST (excerpted) that looks like:

```
> clang++ -std=c++14 -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only file.cpp
|-ClassTemplateDecl 0x563e38c10980 <test_constexpr.cpp:1:1, line:7:1> line:2:7 T
...
| | `-VarDecl 0x563e38c10c98 <line:6:3, col:28> col:24 Y 'const int' static constexpr cinit
| |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x563e38c10d00 <col:28> 'int' NonTypeTemplateParm 0x563e38c10878 'X' 'int'
| `-ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl 0x563e38c10d78 <line:1:1, line:7:1> line:2:7 class T 
...
|   |-VarDecl 0x563e38c110c8 <line:6:3, col:28> col:24 Y 'const int' static constexpr cinit
|   | `-SubstNonTypeTemplateParmExpr 0x563e38c11160 <col:28> 'int' <== MISSING in C++17 BELOW
|   |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x563e38c11140 <col:28> 'int' 42          <== MISSING in C++17 BELOW
```

and things work fine (assuming `decl` is the second `VarDecl` for `Y`, I'm able to access `42` by `decl->getInit()`).

With `clang++ -std=c++17`, however, I get the new AST:

```
> clang++ -std=c++17 -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only file.cpp
|-ClassTemplateDecl 0x56114838ff40 <test_constexpr.cpp:1:1, line:7:1> line:2:7 T
...
| | `-VarDecl 0x561148390258 <line:6:3, col:28> col:24 Y 'const int' static inline constexpr cinit
| |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x5611483902c0 <col:28> 'int' NonTypeTemplateParm 0x56114838fe38 'X' 'int'
| `-ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl 0x561148390338 <line:1:1, line:7:1> line:2:7 class T 
...
|   |-VarDecl 0x561148390688 <line:6:3, col:24> col:24 Y 'const int' static constexpr
```

in which the initializing expression for `Y` (`-IntegerLiteral 0x563e38c11140 <col:28> 'int' 42`) no longer appears. Including a use of `Y` like `int z = Y` in the class definition causes the initializer to reappear.

**Questions**

1. Should I expect not to see the initializer expression in the AST above in `clang++ -std=c++17`?
2. If so, what's the best way to access the initializer for `Y` in `T<42> foo` from within an LLVM-9.x plugin?

Thanks! And please let me know if I've left out relevant information -- I'll be happy to update the question to provide it.